# R: tidyr, getting scope and environments right when incorporating tidyr functions into custom functions

Tags: r, scope, environment-variables, dplyr, tidyr

**Solution** see comments, "*After updating my version of R, and restarting the sever, this issue is no longer present. May it never return. There was no issue with scope or local/global environments, just some bug. Thanks @MrFlick for pointing me in the right direction.*"

---

I am curious if folk can explain (or point to good, new-programmer-friendly documentation or text) to help me probably incorporate tidyr (and plyr, dplyr, and other Hadleyverse packages) into custom functions.  The issue below clearly has a scope/local environment issue I don't fully grasp.

Thanks in advance!

### Reproducible Examples

```
messy <- data.frame(
  name = c("Wilbur", "Petunia", "Gregory"),
  a = c(67, 80, 64),
  b = c(56, 90, 50)
)
```

Outside of a custom function, here is a use of tidyr:

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
messy %>%
  gather(drug, heartrate, a:b) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(drug))

messy %>%
  gather(drug, heartrate, 2:do.call("ncol",list(messy))) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(drug))
```

Both return:

> ```
>      name drug heartrate
> 1  Wilbur    b        56
> 2 Petunia    b        90
> 3 Gregory    b        50
> 4  Wilbur    a        67
> 5 Petunia    a        80
> 6 Gregory    a        64
> ```

These types of operations are obviously quite useful in larger more complex custom functions, but I encounter the following issue:

```
foo1 <- function(DF){

  DF %>%
    gather(drug, heartrate, 2:ncol(DF)) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(drug))

}

foo2 <- function(DF){

  DF %>%
    gather(drug, heartrate, 2:do.call(ncol,list(DF))) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(drug))

}

foo1(messy)
```

> ```
>   Error in ncol(DF) : object 'DF' not found
> ```

```
foo2(messy)
```

> ```
>   Error in do.call(ncol, list(DF)) : object 'DF' not found
> ```

The do.call version in foo2 is motivated by a [similar recent stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752976/r-dplyr-package-bind-rows-failing-when-calls-a-custom-function) that wasn't all that helpful in the end.

---

### Bad Workarounds

One horrible solution that I've been using is to create a global variable

```
fooLISH <- function(DF){
  NCOLS <<- ncol(DF)

  DF %>%
    gather(drug, heartrate, 2:NCOLS) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(drug))
}
```

Or to pass an additional argument into the custom function.

---

But I would love to use this question as a teaching moment for me and others who have run up to this problem.

---

Results from `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
 [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tnet_3.0.11      survival_2.37-7  igraph_0.7.1     tidyr_0.2.0      RODBC_1.3-10     ggplot2_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.1       reshape2_1.4    
 [9] data.table_1.9.2 dplyr_0.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-34      Rcpp_0.11.2      assertthat_0.1   colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.2    
 [9] magrittr_1.0.1   munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.1.1   proto_0.3-10     scales_0.2.4     stringi_0.4-1    stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly the code you are running? Are you sure the data.frame name you use in the function matches the parameter name? I can not replicate those errors. Can you show the output of `sessionInfo()` so we can see what versions of tidyr, dplyr, and magrittr you are using?

Comment: Well, you have an older version of `magrittr`. I might try `update.packages("magrittr")`. But i think it's more likely you have a typo in what you've posted here as a reproducible example. Have you tried to copy/paste this code into a new R session?

Comment: I have taken both your suggestions (update 'magrittr' and reset my session) getting the same errors

Comment: You know what.... I tried it on another machine that had R installed more recently, without issue. Perhaps the problem is resolved updating `R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)'

Comment: It worked for me in "R version 3.1.0". When you restarted R you only ran the code above? Did it restore a workspace when you restarted? Something isn't matching up here.

Comment: I restarted the machine (and have been updating my version of R). Works now.  Though I regret this wasn't a good teaching moment for me about Scope, happy you helped me resolve the issue @MrFlick!

Comment: After updating my version of R, and restarting the sever, this issue is no longer present. May it never return. There was no issue with scope or local/global environments, just some bug. Thanks @MrFlick for pointing me in the right direction.